# how to mark checkbox true for particular record

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, trigger, visualforce-component

I am facing problem in marking checkbox true. Below is my cases

Case1:(**It is correct and working**)

I need records which have duplicate names and do not have any opportunity or contact associated with them.
If the names are same and they have any of the Opportunities or the contacts linked then mark them as duplicates. E.g; if there are 2 such records then mark any 1 of them as 
duplicate.

Case 2:(**Wrong result**)

Suppose, there are a total of 3 duplicate records(with the same names) out of which 1 record is having either opportunity or contact or even both associated with it
and remaining 2 do not have any such relationship, then these should be marked as duplicate.

But, in my case it is marking one checkbox(duplicate__c) as true

```
List<Account> actLst = new List<Account>();
Set<String> userNames = new Set<String>();

List<Account> accList = [SELECT Name,Id  , Prospect_Code__c  , duplicate__C  FROM Account where Id Not
                           In (Select AccountId from Contact) And Id Not In (Select AccountId from Opportunity)];                        


for(Account account_i : accList)
{
     if(!userNames.contains(account_i.Name)) {
        userNames.add(account_i.Name);

    } else {
        account_i.duplicate__c = true;
        actLst.add(account_i);
    }
    system.debug('actLst >> ' + actLst);
    update actLst;

}
```

Comment: I don't really understand, what your problem is. Could you please rephrase your question? What is your task? What do you want to accomplish? And please do not use any abbreviations like "Cont" or "opp" in fluid text. That doesn't help anybody who wants to help you. People simply turn away, when they read something like that on SO.

Comment: I edited the problem please revert back if you find any solutions @Johannes

Comment: Hi Palash, to be clear on your failing scenario: You have three accounts with the same name. One of those three accounts has a contact and / or an opportunity linked. The other two accounts do not have any contacts nor opportunities linked. And you would like to mark these two accounts as a duplicate by setting the accounts' field "duplicate__c" to true. Is that right?

Comment: Correct. But in  my case it is returning 1 record(duplicate__c)= true. So i need tworecord to be true

Comment: Ok. I'll just tell you what your SOQL-Statement does. Maybe you'll understand, why just one of those two records gets marked / updated: You fetch all accounts, that do not have a contact linked, and that do not have an opportunity linked.

Comment: You need to fetch the account that has a a contact or opportunity linked. Then put its name into your names-set. You currently do not use this account. You fetch all accounts without contacts or opportunities. You then take the first of the potential duplicates and put its name into the set. This account then gets ignored, although you want it to be marked as a duplicate. Did I articulate myself in an understandable way? :)

Comment: Correct , and also among duplicate for the  first time whenever the duplicate name come it shouldn't me marked checked(i.e true) and all the rest duplicate  name should be marked checked true-----which is CASE 1 ----But i need to solve case 2

Comment: In your case 2, as in the SOQL query, you are querying only those records which do not have any contacts or opportunity associated to them, so instead of getting 3 records you are getting only 2 out of which only 1 is being marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Palash in my previous comment I told you the solution. Krishnan re-iterated that solution.